# Nginx non-www redirect to www with SSL not working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have been working with this for hours and still can't see what's the problem with my config. Kindly see below.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128...;

    location / {
        include    uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass    unix:/my_socket/site.sock;
    }    

    location /static/ {
        alias /my_static/location/;
    }

    location /media  {
        alias /my_media/location/;
    }



    location ~ /.well-known{
        allow all;
    }
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

When I try to access *example.com*, *www.example.com* it redirects to **https://www.example.com**(which is what I want) but the page is not working unless I remove the last line code below.

```
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

After removing the line above, all links are working well but not redirecting to **www**.

---

Machine:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) with uWSGI
- DJango 1.8.4 running in Google Cloud Platform (Compute Engine)

Comment: Please run `curl -I ${YOUR_SITE}` and show the output.

Comment: The configuration you've provided will form an infinite loop. You're not even serving any content in your 443 block.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Kindly see the updated sample config. Thanks!

Comment: @aldesabido, please remove the `return` statement from your 443 block, it has no purpose there and it will continue to break your config

Comment: I removed the **return** statement and everything works fine. Now my problem is how can I redirect the **non-www** to **www**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a summary, the correct way to configure these redirects is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128...;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ... rules for the actual website ...
}
```

So, we have a server block for http for domains `example.com` and `www.example.com` doing the redirects.

Then we have a server block for https for domain `example.com` doing the redirect.

Then we have the server block for https for domain `www.example.com`, which contains the setup for the actual website.

Comment: Thanks for providing the whole code. I didn't know that you can create a two server block with the same port. This way I can now redirect not just the **example.com** but also the **https://example.com** to **https://www.example.com**

Comment: --
not just the **example.com** but also the **https ://example.com** to **https ://www.example.com**

Comment: Yes, you need only to make sure that have only one port + hostname combination in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comment, you should add content in your 443 block.

For example, you should add upstream and forward all requests there.

Comment: @aldesabido, just add additional server section with `server_name example.com` where put your 301 forward to www.example.com.

Comment: Is there a problem with the first server section?

Comment: @aldesabido there is no problem with firs section, it's accept requests for example.com and www.example.com. I don't know how browsers handle www, but in your case it's easy to create two server sections with www and without.