# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with WWW in Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, http, redirect, https

I am using letsencrypt ssl. When i access site with domain.com, it gets redirected to https://domain.com but i want https://www.domain.com !

I have added www as alias for domain.com in dns panel for accessing site with www. but Now i am getting double redirection.

First redirection : domain.com to https:// domain.com, 
Second redirection : https:// domain.com to https:// www.domain.com

I want to achieve this in single 301 redirection.
already tried multiple solutions given in SF. but it didn't work.
Anyone got idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx non-www redirect to www with SSL not working](http://serverfault.com/questions/808346/nginx-non-www-redirect-to-www-with-ssl-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the nginx configuration and your letsencrypt certificate includes both domain.com and www.domain.com, something like this should work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
  return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

  # the rest of your config
}
```

I believe the SSL certificate needs to include both domains because in the case of requests to https://domain.com the SSL handshake for domain.com occurs before the 301 redirect is triggered.

I suppose you could also have separate certificates for each domain and adjust the certificate paths accordingly.

Comment: this code doesn't seems to working ! i have tried multiple times but it gives error. "duplicate listen 0.0.0.0:443 in /var/www/site.com/conf/nginx/ssl.conf:1 !

Comment: That error means you have two "listen 443" lines within the same server block which isn't allowed.