# nginx redirect based on domain name

Tags: nginx, ssl, domain

I have a django web app which run on server with IP address `xx.xxx.105.49` and domain as `www.example1.com`

Below is my nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  example1.com  www.example1.com ;
 
  location / { 
    return 301    https://www.example1.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example1.com  www.example1.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/company/company.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/company/www.company.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  20m;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;  # ~ 40,000 sessions
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # SSLv2
#    ssl_ciphers          ALL:!aNull:!eNull:!SSLv2:!kEDH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/apps/webapp/company/new_media/;
  }

  location /media/ {
    alias  /home/apps/webapp/company/media/;
  }
}
```

when i type `www.example1.com` or `example1.com`from browser it take me to `https://www.example1.com` as expected but, now I have configured another domain(`example2.company.com`) to route to the same server `(xx.xxx.105.49)` and the actual problem is

when ever i type `https://example2.company.com`(secure), server was serving me the webapp with same domain `example2.company.com`

But when i use `http://example2.company.com`, my server was redirecting to `www.example1.com` which was not i want, so how can make some changes to the above nginx config file in such a way that if some one tries to access `example2.company.com` using http or https it should redirect to `https://example2.company.com` like below

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  example1.com  www.example1.com ;

  location / { 
    return 301    https://www.example1.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  example2.company.com  www.example2.company.com ;

  location / { 
    return 301    https://www.example2.company.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with all related virtualhosts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx non-www redirect to www with SSL not working](http://serverfault.com/questions/808346/nginx-non-www-redirect-to-www-with-ssl-not-working)

Comment: Are you looking for `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to setup a new vhost for example2.xyz.com. Nginx will read the domain name first then call respectively conf file otherwise default conf.

In nginx conf of vhost listen port 80 seperatly for both example1 and example2 or you can add listen 80 in default conf too for redirection to https.

Use map module for mapping multiple redirection like below example.

```
map $http_host $new {
  'exp1.xyz.com' '1';
  'exp2.xyz.com' '2';
}

server {
  listen 80;
  if ($new = '1') {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://exp1.xyz.com$1 redirect;
  }
  if ($new = '2') {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://exp2.xyz.com$1 redirect;
  }
}
```

For creating vhosts in nginx refer this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

Comment: you advise this over `if ($host ~* "(www\.)?domain\.(com|nl)$") {
    rewrite ^/old/?$ domain.com/new permanent;
}`

Comment: Rules based on if statements are not good in ngninx environment - please read https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Gupta for contributing this. Your answer worked like a charm! :-)

Comment: @lupo, the title of the article you linked is "If is Evil… when used in location context".  Here, `if` is used in the `server` context.